How to process files in an S3 bucket one by one through AWS Lambda until no more files remain
The scenario is this :

I am expecting to receive files from various sources through Appflow into an S3 bucket
location. The files may come in at different times of the day, multiple times.

I am hoping to use AWS Lambda to trigger various AWS Glue ETL workflows based on what file
i receive which i shall compute through the AWS Lambda custom logic.


Now the bottleneck is that that the files need to be processed one by one, and cannot be run concurrently at the same time. If files arrive in my S3 location while my workflow is still up and running, how do I deal with that scenario and ensure those files are processed too until no more files are left in my S3 path, after the latest file is done processing through the Glue workflow successful execution?
Note: Once a file is done it can be moved from that S3 path into some archive directory or deleted. Using a python based lambda approach.

You can create an S3 Event that will trigger automatically when an object is created in an Amazon S3 bucket. You can configure the event to store a message in an Amazon SQS queue.
You can then configure your Lambda function:

To trigger off the Amazon SQS queue
With a Reserved Concurrency of 1, which will limit it to only running one instance of the Lambda function at any time

This way, each file will get processed individually.
It is not required to 'move' the S3 object once it has been processed but if you won't need it anymore then it is best to delete it after processing otherwise you will have a large number of files doing nothing for you but costing money to store.

It is possible that this will also work if you directly trigger the Lambda function from the S3 event, but it might cause problems if the messages queue for a long time so I recommended using SQS in the middle. You could experiment without it, though.
